# Randomly my AWS Cognito signup stops working, login works though

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

On random times my signup form on the website stops working. It gets 400 error from cognito auth. However login still works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwt47.png)

I am not sure how to approach this problem?